# 0.431776 Initramfs unpacking failed:Decoding failed (after update from 20.04 to 20.10)

Tags: upgrade, 20.04, initramfs, 20.10

I upgraded to Ubuntu 20.10 from 20.04. Then after restarting it says "Initramfs unpacking failed:Decoding failed."

The screen says:

```
[0.431776] Initramfs unpacking failed: Decoding failed
/dev/sad1:recovering journal
/dev/sda1: Clean, 277874/2191168 files, 3128076/8749824 blocks
[3.774884] Bluetooth: hci0: unexpected event for opcode 0xfc2f
[4.292226] pci 0000:08:00.1: can't change power state from D3cold to D0 (config space inaccessible)
[4.292272] snd_hda_intel 0000:08:00.1: can't change power state from D3hot to D0 (config space inaccessible)
[4.395874] hdaudio hdaudioC2D0: no AFG or MFG node found
[4.395889] hdaudio hdaudioC2D1: no AFG or MFG node found
[4.395900] hdaudio hdaudioC2D2: no AFG or MFG node found
[4.395908] hdaudio hdaudioC2D3: no AFG or MFG node found
[4.395917] hdaudio hdaudioC2D4: no AFG or MFG node found
[4.395925] hdaudio hdaudioC2D5: no AFG or MFG node found
[4.395934] hdaudio hdaudioC2D6: no AFG or MFG node found
[4.395943] hdaudio hdaudioC2D7: no AFG or MFG node found
[4.395946] snd_hda_intel 0000:08:00.1: no coded initialized
you are in emergency mode. After logging in, type "journalctl -xb" to view system logs, "systemctl reboot" to reboot, "systemctl default" or "exit" to boot into default mode.
Press enter for maintainance (or press Control-D to continue):
```

Comment: Hey S Ghimire! How did you upgrade to 20.10 from 20.04? Can you let us know the steps you followed?

Comment: It appers on desktop: Update to 20.10. So i update using software update on desktop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First make sure you disabled secure boot in BIOS.

Initramfs can’t compress default format and messaging error in decoding.
So you need change to gzip.

Open terminal and paste:

sudo gedit /etc/initramfs-tools/initramfs.conf

After that, find COMPRESS=lz4 and change it to COMPRESS=gzip

When it’s done, click save in right corner and close this file.

Finally just paste into terminal:

sudo update-initramfs -u

reboot

... However, error you are in emergency mode is more important.  Your etc/fstab is wrong and waste time by checking disk every boot.
Also seems like couple of your drivers aren’t recognized well.

Comment: Thank You for the help.

Comment: You welcome, new member.